# Does anybody know what the ARP cache timeout is for macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos

Does anyone know deafult ARP cache timeout for macOS Sierra?

Comment: The ARP cache is stored in the system routing table as dynamically-created host
 routes.  The route to a directly-attached Ethernet network is installed as a
 ``cloning'' route (one with the RTF_CLONING flag set), causing routes to individual
 hosts on that network to be created on demand.  These routes time out periodically
 (normally 20 minutes after validated; entries are not validated when not in use).

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard time out value for routes stored in an arp table.  For instance, on Cisco gear, it's 4 hours.

The `arp` utility that macOS uses is the [one from BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/arp.4) and it's time out is 20 minutes if the host has been validated. Static entries don't time out, but can be over written by network traffic.  Permanent entries also do not time out and cannot be over written.